# Summarize output of table to simple columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I currently have this table and I want to sum the total number of purchases per each ID.

**Input:**

| id | purchases | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | need | 1:00 |
| a | want | 1:30 |
| a | none | 2:00 |
| b | need | 1:15 |
| b | want | 1:30 |
| c | none | 1:10 |
| c | none | 1:30 |
| d | none | 2:00 |
| d | need | 2:10 |
| d | want | 2:15 |
| d | none | 2:35 |
| e | none | 3:10 |
| e | none | 3:50 |
| f | need | 2:55 |
| f | want | 3:15 |
| f | need | 3:20 |

the purchases column was primarily not existent and instead there were item names. so I created this column first and then proceeded to try to reach the below output

**Desired first output:** total items bought, number of needs and wants separately, the output column is yes **if first purchase is a need**, no if it isn't, none if there were no purchases

| id | total | need | want | output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2 | 1 | 1 | yes |
| b | 2 | 1 | 1 | yes |
| c | 0 | 0 | 0 | none |
| d | 2 | 1 | 1 | no |
| e | 0 | 0 | 0 | none |
| f | 3 | 2 | 1 | yes |

I am using dplyr so I would appreciate the suggested code to be feasible for adding in a dplyr pipeline.

**What I tried to do**

```r
actions %>% group_by (id) %>% arrange(id) %>%
  mutate(purchases = ifelse(type == "Buy" & obj_category == "Books" | type == "Buy" & obj_category == "Car" | type=="Buy" & obj_category == "Business" | type == "Buy", "need",
                            ifelse(type == "Buy" & obj_category == "Sweets" | type == "Buy" & obj_category == "Electronics" | type == "Buy" & obj_category == "Business" | type == "Buy" & obj_category == "House", "want", "none"))) %>%
  summarise(need = ifelse(purchases == "need", 1, 0),
            want = ifelse(purchases == "want", 1, 0))
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(need = sum(purchases == "need"),
            want = sum(purchases == "want"),
            total = need + want,
            output = case_when(first(purchases) == "need" ~ "yes",
                               total == 0 ~ "none",
                               TRUE ~ "no"))

# # A tibble: 6 × 5
#   id     need  want total output
#   <chr> <int> <int> <int> <chr> 
# 1 a         1     1     2 yes   
# 2 b         1     1     2 yes   
# 3 c         0     0     0 none  
# 4 d         1     1     2 no    
# 5 e         0     0     0 none  
# 6 f         2     1     3 yes
```

---

A general version if there are more categories in `purchases`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)

df %>% 
  tabyl(id, purchases) %>%
  select(-none) %>%
  adorn_totals("col") %>%
  left_join(
    df %>% group_by(id) %>%
      summarise(output = case_when(purchases[1] == "need" ~ "yes",
                                   all(purchases == "none") ~ "none",
                                   TRUE ~ "no")))
```

---

###### Data

```r
df <- structure(list(id = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "d", 
"d", "d", "d", "e", "e", "f", "f", "f"), purchases = c("need", 
"want", "none", "need", "want", "none", "none", "none", "need", 
"want", "none", "none", "none", "need", "want", "need"), time = c("1:00", 
"1:30", "2:00", "1:15", "1:30", "1:10", "1:30", "2:00", "2:10", 
"2:15", "2:35", "3:10", "3:50", "2:55", "3:15", "3:20")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

Comment: Thank you! Can I please ask, is there a way to write this part (mutate(purchases= ifelse(type=="Buy" & obj_category=="Books"|type=="Buy" & obj_category=="Car"|type=="Buy" & obj_category=="Business"|type=="Buy",) "without needing to list the "& condition" of "type="Buy" in the ifelse statement?

Comment: would this still apply if I have more than 2 conditions within the brackets? I am getting an error

Comment: @Eman You only need to write type == "Buy" once because `cond.1 & cond.2 | cond.1 & cond.3` is equivalent to `cond.1 & (cond.2 | cond.3)`. Of course this feature applies if you have more than 2 conditions.

Comment: The first code you constructed doesn't give any "yes" at all in the actual data set for the output column although the case happens multiple times. I think it might be because I was anticipating that none wouldn't be an effect in the purchases column. Just to reiterate, for example in (id "d"), I don't want to consider the "none" at the beginning, the decision shall only be based on which comes first, is it need or want. so in case of (id "d") output=yes as need comes first. I am trying to find a way to grasp that but I didn't figure it out yet. sorry for any confusion.

Comment: I started the output part with ```output = case_when(purchases=="need" | purchases=="want",```  but I am not able to connect the rest of the condition. I am trying to say that by looking only at purchases being need or want, find the first observation per id to see if it's a need or want. If need then yes, if want then no

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with `dplyr` and `janitor`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)

df %>% 
  janitor::tabyl(id, purchases) %>% 
  left_join(df %>% group_by(id) %>% slice(1), by = "id") %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(total = sum(c_across(need:want))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(purchases = ifelse(purchases == "need", "yes", "no"),
         purchases = ifelse(total == 0, "none", purchases)) %>% 
  select(-c(time, total))
```

Which gives:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 5
  id     need  none  want purchases
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    
1 a         1     1     1 yes      
2 b         1     0     1 yes      
3 c         0     2     0 no       
4 d         1     2     1 no       
5 e         0     2     0 no       
6 f         2     0     1 yes
```